# flutter/dart await returning result too early sqlite db operations

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

**Edited to include the addFileToDB code**

I am developing my 1st dart/flutter app and trying to understand why my use of async/await is not working.

I have 2 code examples below.  1st example does not work. 2nd sample works but I don't understand why the delay is needed.  Scenario is that the addFileToDb inserts sqlite records but loadDbFileNames fails to pull the data back out unless I introduce the delay.  To me this seems to suggest that "await" in the line "await addFileToDb(record.key, record.value);" did not work.

```
Future<void> addFilesToDb(Map<String, String> filesMap) async {
    _chgNState(NSDBFILESLOADING);
    for (var record in filesMap.entries) {
      await addFileToDb(record.key, record.value);
    }
    _chgNState(NSDBFILESLOADDONE);
    await loadDbFileNames();
  }

Future<void> loadDbFileNames() async {
    _chgNState(NSDBFILENAMESLOADING);
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> rows =
        await db.rawQuery("select distinct(FileName) from OrderedLists");
    dbFileNames.clear();
    rows.forEach((row) {
      dbFileNames.add(row["FileName"]);
    });
    _chgNState(NSDBFILENAMESLOADDONE);
  }
```

This code works.

```
Future<void> addFilesToDb(Map<String, String> filesMap) async {
    _chgNState(NSDBFILESLOADING);
    for (var record in filesMap.entries) {
      await addFileToDb(record.key, record.value);
    }
    _chgNState(NSDBFILESLOADDONE);
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
      loadDbFileNames();
    });
  }

Future<void> loadDbFileNames() async {
    _chgNState(NSDBFILENAMESLOADING);
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> rows =
        await db.rawQuery("select distinct(FileName) from OrderedLists");
    dbFileNames.clear();
    rows.forEach((row) {
      dbFileNames.add(row["FileName"]);
    });
    _chgNState(NSDBFILENAMESLOADDONE);
  }
```

This code is the same between both version (working and non-working)

```
Future<void> addFileToDb(String fileName, String fullFilePath) async {
    var returnValue = false;
    //strip the extension from the file name
    fileName = fileName.split(".")[0];
    //make sure file name is not already in the database
    var qs = "select count(1) from OrderedLists where FileName='" +
        fileName +
        "' group by FileName";
    var count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery(qs));
    if (count == null) {
      Stream<List<int>> stream = File(fullFilePath).openRead();
      stream.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(LineSplitter()).listen((data) {
        List<String> recList = data.split(String.fromCharCode(9));
        var ListName = recList[0];
        var ItemName = recList[1];
        var ItemOrder = recList[2];
        if (ListName != "ListName") {
          var values = "'" +
              fileName +
              "','" +
              ListName +
              "','" +
              ItemName +
              "'," +
              ItemOrder;
          db.rawInsert(
              "INSERT INTO OrderedLists(FileName,ListName,ItemName,ItemOrder) VALUES(" +
                  values +
                  ")");
        }
      }, onDone: () {
        //TODO
      }, onError: (e) {
        //TODO
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're calling an asynchronous function somewhere but aren't waiting for it to complete. Make sure you enable the `unawaited_futures` lint and check if `dartanalyer` finds anything.

Comment: You have not posted the key piece: what does `addFileToDb` do? You expect it to be finished inserting into the database, but you have not shown us the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my addFileToDb was using async and not waiting so that was my problem.